# Ajax POST Failing Every Time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I have tried multiple ways of sending a post, such as a XMLHttpRequest. All of them ended in the post failing.
I am using XAMPP to run the webpage this is for.

JS

```
var obj = {
        title: $("form input[name=title]").val(),
        desc: $("form input[name=desc]").val(),
        etc...
    };
$.post("newpost.php", {data: JSON.stringify(obj)}, function(response){
    console.log("Response: "+response);
}).fail(function(result){
    console.log("Fail "+result);
});
```

PHP

```
echo $_POST["data"];
```

Comment: What about the request is failing?  What does the network console say about the request?

Comment: Debug debug debug! Browser console is your friend here, so is browser network as Taplar said. Also, never be afraid to pepper your code with var_dumps and print_r!

Comment: Firefox network Monitor shows the status of the post as a white circle with no code. The size and transferred are both 0. The params tab shows that data I want to post is all there. There was absolutely no response to the post. The type is also set to nothing.